# MySQL Update or Rename a Key in JSON

Tags: mysql, json

I'm having this json stored in db

```
{
    "endDate": "2018-10-10",
    "startDate": "2017-09-05", 
    "oldKeyValue": {
        "foo": 1000, 
        "bar": 2000, 
        "baz": 3000
    },
    "anotherValue": 0
}
```

How can I rename `"oldKeyValue"` key to `"newKeyValue"` without knowing the index of the key in an `UPDATE` query? I'm looking for something like this

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET `my_col` = JSON()
```

NOTE: only the key needs to change, the values (i.e. `{"foo": 1000, "bar": 2000, "baz": 3000}`) should remain the same

Comment: What type does column have?

Comment: Without parsing it out to a table, selecting it as something else and reserializing it to json, the easiest way (if it's stored as a string) is gonna be `update table set jsoncolumn = REPLACE(jsoncolumn, '"oldKeyValue":', '"newKeyValue":')` - it should work out because json's structure should be relatively regular, i.e. a string surrounded by quotes and followed by colon should be a key, as it would have to be escaped to be part of a string value

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is no straightforward JSON function to do the same. We can use a combination of some JSON functions.

We will remove the *oldKey-oldValue* pair using [`Json_Remove()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-remove) function, and then [`Json_Insert()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-insert) the *newKey-oldValue* pair.

[`Json_Extract()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) function is used to fetch value corresponding to an input key in the JSON document.

```
UPDATE `my_table` 
SET `my_col` = JSON_INSERT(
                           JSON_REMOVE(my_col, '$.oldKeyValue'), 
                           '$.newKeyValue', 
                           JSON_EXTRACT(my_col, '$.oldKeyValue')
                          );
```

**[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kHywwDrV1acnxb3x6HkWrT/0)**

```
SET @my_col := '{"endDate": "2018-10-10", "startDate": "2017-09-05", "oldKeyValue": {"foo": 1000, "bar": 2000, "baz": 3000}, "anotherValue": 0}';

SET @new_col := JSON_INSERT(
                            JSON_REMOVE(@my_col, '$.oldKeyValue'), 
                            '$.newKeyValue',
                            JSON_EXTRACT(@my_col,'$.oldKeyValue')
                          );

SELECT @new_col;
```

**Result**

```
| @new_col                                                                                                                        |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| {"endDate": "2018-10-10", "startDate": "2017-09-05", "newKeyValue": {"bar": 2000, "baz": 3000, "foo": 1000}, "anotherValue": 0} |
```

---

As an alternative to `Json_Extract()`, we can also use `->` operator to access the Value corresponding to a given Key in the JSON doc.

```
UPDATE `my_table` 
SET `my_col` = JSON_INSERT(
                           JSON_REMOVE(my_col, '$.oldKeyValue'), 
                           '$.newKeyValue', 
                           my_col->'$.oldKeyValue' 
                          );
```

Comment: Beat me to it +1.  I agree that there is no direct function.  So it's either this, or taking a chance on a plain replacement.

Comment: I noticed you change your script. I tried the first one using JSON_INSERT and JSON_REMOVE. Perhaps its better to keep this too along with JSON_EXTRACT  in your answer to avoid confusion

Comment: @Lykos I will; it was not working on fiddle due to some parsing issues at fiddle end. I will update the answer with that also, once i get a fiddle working for it.

Answer (score 34):

I personally prefer another method:

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_col = REPLACE(my_col, '"oldKeyValue":', '"newKeyValue":')
```

This replaces directly the key name in the JSON string without destroying the JSON structure.

I am using the additional `:` in order to avoid an unintentional replacement in a value.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Simple, fast, and safe.  Thanks.

Comment: It might unintentionally alter the structure if the JSON is in nested structure with same key name in different level

Answer (score 1):

Plain text search & replace will only work if the JSON is stored in minified/compact format without extra whitespace in it.