# How to replace member in JSON in MariaDB

Tags: json, mariadb

I have JSON field in a table which contains the following:

```
[{"Example":"2"}]
```

I've seen JSON_REPLACE which will allow me to replace the value of any JSON member, but its the key itself I need to replace, is there a function that will allow me to change the above to:

```
[{"ex":"2"}]
```

Edit, sorry I missed out something important, the JSON is actually in an array.  I need to replace a member in an array element.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53433285/mysql-update-or-rename-a-key-in-json

Comment: @n00b, please see edit, sorry I messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @nOOb for link, have fixed with:

```
UPDATE threats SET jsonParams=
    JSON_INSERT(JSON_REMOVE(jsonParams, '$[2].Example'),
        '$[2].ex', JSON_EXTRACT(jsonParams, '$[2].Example'));
```